Is it possible to convert BertTokenizer to BartTokenizer?
I understand BART and BERT are two architectures available in HuggingFace Transformers. I wondered if I could convert BertTokenizer to a BartTokenizer.
The reason for converting is that a training script requires BartTokenizer format, while the tokenizer I am using is a BertTokenizer.
I saved my tokenizer and the model using save_pretrained to a local folder. The files are as follows:

added_tokens.json
config.json
generation_config.json
pytorch_model.bin
special_tokens_map.json
tokenizer_config.json
tokenizer.json
vocab.txt

For BartTokenizer, it looks for the following files:

vocab.json
merges.txt
tokenizer.json
config.json

How can I "convert" the BertTokenizer to BartTokenizer files? Thanks.

Using the following versions:

transformers 4.28.1
tokenizers 0.13.3
Python 3.10.10

and on another machine (using the latest version available):

transformers 4.45.2
tokenizers 0.20.1
Python 3.12.4


I am not sure that there's a simple way for obtaining merges (merges.txt) from your berttokenizer, but the easiest you can do - add tokens from your bertokenizer:
from transformers import BartTokenizerFast

bert_tokenizer # your tokenizer
bart_tokenizer = BartTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("facebook/bart-base")
bert_tokens = list(bert_tokenizer.vocab.keys())
bart_tokenizer.add_tokens(bert_tokens)


Thanks, but in this way, the original Bert Tokenizer's tokens will also be merged with the Bart's one. Isn't it?

Yes, to add tokens from added_tokens.json, you can use the same code: bart_tokenizer.add_tokens(tokens), where tokens are a list of string tokens read from this json file.

But I want to replace the tokens of BART to BERT ones.

I get it, but BART, as indicated in the answer, uses a merges.txt file for BPE merges. You don't have merges since BERT doesn't use BPE. So, you can (for instance) use the BPE merges file from an existing BART tokenizer as a reference as shown in the answer.

Another solution - train bart-style tokenizer on your corpus.
